# How to send data java and html

Tags: java, html

code JAVA

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class test{

     public static void main (String[] args)throws Exception{
     demoReadall();
     }

     public static void demoReadall(){
          String dates;
          String res;
          String status;
          try{
               FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("RunningSystem.log");
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
               String strLine;
               
               while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)  {
                String[] LineArray = strLine.split("\\|");
                if("BATCH_PAYMENT".equals(LineArray[1])){
                    dates = LineArray[2];
                    res = LineArray[3];
                    status = LineArray[4];    
                System.out.println(dates);
                System.out.println (res);
                System.out.println (status);
                }
               }
               fstream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
     }
}
```

How do you write the front-end code to retrieve information about this code? Please bother me.
I would like to know how to send java and html data, please advise writing and sending data.

Comment: You should use `J2EE`, extend your class from `HTTPServlet` (forgot exact name) which will help you handle HTTP methods like `GET`, `POST` etc.

Comment: I'm just starting out with java, is there an example to see or suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Read about .jsp, servlets or Spring framework ;-)

Comment: I'm just starting out with java, is there an example to see or suggest?

Comment: Maybe this one or search for something similiar: [link](https://www.codejava.net/coding/java-servlet-and-jsp-hello-world-tutorial-with-eclipse-maven-and-apache-tomcat)